# Xcode 5.1 no simulated metrics landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I can't seem to find the simulated metrics "landscape" options as can be seen [here](http://www.techotopia.com/images/8/83/Ios_7_no_autolayout.png).

I have selected the View Controller, and am at the attribute inspector, but I only can choose between freeform and fixed. But there is no landscape option.

Has this been removed? Or should I do this another way. In my project settings I have only checked landscape as a valid screen rotation.

edit: I suppose I can do freeform and fill in the landscape width and height myself. But I am still wondering.

[image: No landscape]

Comment: select "Attribute Inspector" there you can find orientation option.
according to screenshot, you shared you have selected "Size Inspector" that is the only problem.
to select press command+alt+4

Comment: It was hidden. :-( Thanks!